# Neo4j calculate Import time and execution time of query

Tags: neo4j

Please answer these two questions:
1-How to calculate Import time in Neo4j when import CSV FILE and when execute any query.
2-How to speed up loading time in Neo4j when importing a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN datetime() AS currentDateTime` will return the time that the query was executed. The documentation on [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/#functions-datetime) gives more options for working with temporal functions.

To improve import performance, start by checking that you have indexes and constraints in place. [This free course](https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/cypher-indexes-constraints/), and the training that leads up to it in the Neo4j Graph Academy, will help you understand how to implement them.